# Logout the app by Protractor

Tags: protractor

```
<div class="user-nav">
<ul>
    <li hs-gesture="{ handler: toggleDutyStatus }" ng-class="onDuty|switch:{true:'on',false:'off'}" id="user-menu-duty" user-profile-btn-do-not-close="" class="ng-binding on" style="">
        <i ng-hide="onDuty==undefined" ng-class="onDuty|switch:{true:'icon-duty',false:'icon-off-duty'}" class="icon-duty" style=""></i>On Duty
    </li>
    <li ng-show="false" ng-bing="" id="user-menu-settings" class="ng-binding ng-hide"><i class="icon-settings"></i>Settings</li>
    <li hs-gesture="{ handler: changeUnit}" ng-show="canChangeUnit" id="user-menu-unit" class="ng-binding ng-hide"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Change Unit</li>
    <li hs-gesture="{ handler: changePassword}" ng-show="canChangePassword" id="user-menu-change-password" class="ng-binding"><i class="icon-lock-change"></i>Change Password</li>
    <li hs-gesture="{ handler: showAbout}" id="user-menu-about" class="ng-binding"><i class="icon-about"></i>About</li>
    <li hs-gesture="{ handler: showScreenHelp}" ng-show="canShowHelp" id="user-menu-screenhelp" class="ng-binding ng-hide"><i class="icon-question-round"></i>Help</li>
    <li hs-gesture="{ handler: logout}" id="user-menu-logout" class="ng-binding"><i class="icon-lock"></i>Log Out</li>
</ul>
```

Scenario: log out from app. A button has already been clicked form the rest of the script which is not shown. The user has 4 choices and we like 'Log Out' to be double clicked.
What is the best way to do this in Protractor from the above snippet code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get it by id and use [`browser.actions()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) to perform double click:

```
var logout = element(by.id("user-menu-logout"));
browser.actions().doubleClick(logout).perform();
```

Comment: @ alecxe, Thank you Sir. That did it